# Где ошибка? В чём я не прав? Not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Где ошибка? В чём я не прав? Not all arguments converted during string formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даже после выполнения команды `i = bin(i)[2:]` переменная остаётся **строкой**, а не числом, поэтому операция взятия остатка для строки не существует.

Полагаю, Вы забыли привести результат к типу `int`:

```
i = int(bin(i)[2:])
```

UPD: если смотреть на другую часть кода, то тогда можно привести к `int` только `i` в условии: `if int(i) % 2 == 0`. В конце концов, даже если `i` и стала двоичным числом, операция взятия остатка не изменяется: для нечётных число будет `...1`, для чётных — `...0`.